# Android fragment list view array from server side retrieve

Tags: android, listview, fragment

i got code work properly, but i need to change the array data retrieve from my server on finzacomtech[dot]com/testdata[dot]php
below is the code:

```
package com.package.activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.package.R;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    private AndroidFlavorAdapter flavorAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    AndroidFlavor[] androidFlavors = {
            new AndroidFlavor("Cupcake", "1.5", R.drawable.cupcake),
            new AndroidFlavor("Donut", "1.6", R.drawable.donut),
            new AndroidFlavor("Eclair", "2.0-2.1", R.drawable.eclair),
            new AndroidFlavor("Froyo", "2.2-2.2.3", R.drawable.froyo),
            new AndroidFlavor("GingerBread", "2.3-2.3.7", R.drawable.gingerbread),
            new AndroidFlavor("Honeycomb", "3.0-3.2.6", R.drawable.honeycomb),
            new AndroidFlavor("Ice Cream Sandwich", "4.0-4.0.4", R.drawable.icecream),
            new AndroidFlavor("Jelly Bean", "4.1-4.3.1", R.drawable.jellybean),
            new AndroidFlavor("KitKat", "4.4-4.4.4", R.drawable.kitkat),
            new AndroidFlavor("Lollipop", "5.0-5.1.1", R.drawable.lollipop)
    };

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        flavorAdapter = new AndroidFlavorAdapter(getActivity(), Arrays.asList(androidFlavors));

        // Get a reference to the ListView, and attach this adapter to it.
        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_flavor);
        listView.setAdapter(flavorAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

I just need change how to retrieve my data on finzacomtech[dot]com/testdata[dot]php like a format this code below

```
AndroidFlavor[] androidFlavors = {
                new AndroidFlavor("Cupcake", "1.5", R.drawable.cupcake),
                new AndroidFlavor("Donut", "1.6", R.drawable.donut),
                new AndroidFlavor("Eclair", "2.0-2.1", R.drawable.eclair),
                new AndroidFlavor("Froyo", "2.2-2.2.3", R.drawable.froyo),
                new AndroidFlavor("GingerBread", "2.3-2.3.7", R.drawable.gingerbread),
                new AndroidFlavor("Honeycomb", "3.0-3.2.6", R.drawable.honeycomb),
                new AndroidFlavor("Ice Cream Sandwich", "4.0-4.0.4", R.drawable.icecream),
                new AndroidFlavor("Jelly Bean", "4.1-4.3.1", R.drawable.jellybean),
                new AndroidFlavor("KitKat", "4.4-4.4.4", R.drawable.kitkat),
                new AndroidFlavor("Lollipop", "5.0-5.1.1", R.drawable.lollipop)
        };
```

Comment: create and echo json array of `AndroidFlavor` objects from server.

Comment: Thank you Aditya for response, i already make json on serverside  finzacomtech[dot]com/testdata[dot]php, you can open it, but i stuck when i try to convert structure data like androidFlavors = { 'data fom array php' }

Comment: You can use Gson. It can create a `ArrayList<AndroidFlavor>` from the json string. OR you can create JsonArray object from the string and loop through it to get all objects.

Comment: please give me advice best tutorial for listview on fragment serverside... thank you, before...

Comment: can you share the response json string from server?

Comment: thats code above working properly, no error, i just need to replace inside AndroidFlavor[] androidFlavors = { ------------ from json data on server ------------ }